# Attaching a 2-handle to a once-twisted unlink in the boundary of the 4-ball

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, 4-manifolds, surgery-theory, handle-decomposition

1. Consider the 3-sphere $S_3$ with an unlink loop $L$ whose tubular neighborhood is identified with the solid torus $B_2\times S_1$ with one twist, i.e., such that the image of $x\times S_1$ (where $x$ is a fixed point on the boundary of $B_2$) has linking number $1$ with $L$. Now, cut the solid torus and glue it back in with a modular $S$-transformation in between. In other words, apply a 1-surgery. What is the resulting 3-manifold?
2. Now add a fourth dimension, considering $S_3=\partial B_4$. Attach a 2-handle along the solid torus from the previous paragraph. What is the resulting 4-manifold with boundary? The boundary should be the result from 1).

My motivation behind the question is that this surgery should compute the chiral central charge of a modular tensor category. I would therefore expect the resulting 4-manifold to be $\mathbb{C}P(2)$ with something simple removed, like a 4-ball, or the tubular neighborhood of an unlink.

I asked the same question [on the other math stackexchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460682/487705), but didn't get any answers there. Feel free to answer there instead of here if you want.

Comment: You are right. The 3-manifold is $S^3$ and the $4$-manifold is $\mathbb{C}P^2\setminus B^4$.

Comment: See http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/MKirbyCalculus.pdf p47.